# CSS over-flow: hidden or scroll not working with span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a demo site to show text data.

In the text box, user inserts too much character.

So, I want it can be a scroll to display all text.

I using the property of CSS:

```css
span {
   display: block;
   overflow: scroll;
   height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<span>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
I am a span<br/>
<span>
```

But I can't scroll down.

You can see at:

[image]

Comment: "*[..]site to show text data.*" -- If it is text data, why not just use a `textarea` and be done with?

Comment: @freedomn-m I understand the term in StackOverflow. I also know my question is ugly. But I don't have the method to resolve that. Which a minimal code, it's working.

Comment: The minimal part is the minimal code to reproduce the issue, not just minimal code,   So you can either start with nothing and add parts (eg your site.css (or equivalent)) until it happens, then rollback step by step to find exactly what the cause is; or you can start with the cause and remove parts (eg comments bits in your site.css) until it stops being an issue, then you know what's causing it.

Comment: You also might like to use the browser built-in DOM inspector.  Your issue is not that the span is not overflowing (in fact it doesn't actually even have overflow:scroll on, but that's irrelevant).  The issue is here is the containing wrapper has overflow hidden : `<div class="frameallcontent smart" id="smartdichvuhoatnao" style="overflow: hidden;">`  (although changing this seems to have no effect... so perhaps not the final/only issue)

Comment: Wow, seem I lost brains because of too much problem on today. Thanks for your comment. You save my life. Thank you very much @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1):

Works for me? I suspect you have another rule overriding this one. Try adding !important to the overflow: scroll declaration.

```css
span {
   display: block;
   overflow: scroll !important;
   height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<span>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum venenatis, justo quis mollis volutpat, nibh enim</p>
</span>
```

Comment: You should be test in my demo site. It's not working.

Comment: Did you post a link?

Comment: Yes. I tried. You can add code to my site from Chrome Dev Tools. You can't scroll. You must drag content in <span>.

Comment: If you agree the code above works, which it does, then something else in your code is overriding the scroll property. I'm afraid I cannot take the time to debug your live site, unless you want to employ me ;) My answer was technically correct, so I'd appreciate if you accepted it :)

Comment: Your answer was "works for me" and you expect it to be accepted?

Comment: No, my answer was add !important to the declaration to override whatever else was affecting the span

Comment: @mayersdesign , with suggest of freedomn-m I resolved my problem. Your answer not resolve my problem.

Comment: No problem, well done. Next time I will remember not to use the code posted here, but instead to fire-up my debug tools and immediately jump onto the OP's website to debug their site. In fact, I might make this my new career, it's sure to pay the bills.

Comment: @mayersdesign, so sorry. I'm really appreciates spent a time to help me. But it not success in my case. So, I just vote your answer.